# how to see output of function in console.log?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, console.log

I have a code of about 70 odd lines.Just for testing purpose i want to check the output of what a function is returning.
When I dumped my entire code in the console.log it did returned some array!!!
But when I dump a particaular function from my code,it displays error.
Is it possible to check the output of function in console.

Not necessary,but my fiddle--->
http://jsfiddle.net/ddfsb/4/

I want to check what these 2 functions are returning-:

```
var getColumnCell = function (d, col)
{
    var arr = d[1], ret = null

    for( var  i in arr ) {
    ret = arr[i][0] == col ? arr[i] : ret;
    if (ret) break;
    }
    return ret;
}

var mapCell = function (row)
{
return columns.map(function(column) {
return { column : column, value : getColumnCell(row, column) }
})
}
```

Comment: *"I want to check what these 2 functions are returning"* Why not just use the debugger built into the browser to step through the functions? When you're sitting on the `return ret` line, you can look at the value in `ret` in the debugger.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:i am sorry but i am not clear with what you are trying to say?

Comment: I'm saying that any browser that has `console.log` has a debugger built into it. Use it. If you don't know how (and all of us didn't know how at some point), search for information on your browser's debugger. In most browsers, pressing F12 opens it (IE8+, Chrome, probabyl others). You can set break points, single-step through code, inspect the values in variables, ...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:ok.thx..i remember when I posted a question on prototype,constructor and methods...You replied with a fab answer that even a 10year old would understand.Keep up the good work!!!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:yes i know that...i have used console.log.I am completely  familiar with what you are telling,but dint knew what to do in this case!!!thats why posted this question.It would obviously be silly to you..hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an update to your script.

Please check out [this new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddfsb/5/).

I am logging to console the return values of those functions.

In the `getColumnCell` function, I had to store the return value in a variable, and had to `JSON.stringify` the console output, as it was returning Object's.

The console output looks like this:

```
getColumnCell is returning parties,0,0.9 
getColumnCell is returning null 
getColumnCell is returning null 
getColumnCell is returning null 
getColumnCell is returning null 
getColumnCell is returning null
mapCell is returning [{"column":"parties","value":["parties",0,0.9]},{"column":"star-speak","value":null},{"column":"signature","value":null},{"column":"fashion","value":null},{"column":"live-responsibly","value":null},{"column":"indulge","value":null}]
```

Comment: thx,and what if i want to check for any function in general?just asking

Comment: Probably the best way is to do something like this in your functions: `return ret = 'something';`, then within Chrome's developer tools (F12), go to the Sources tab and find your script. Set a break point on the line after the return statement (probably a `}`) by clicking the line number beside that line of code, and set up a watch for the variable named `ret` in the Watch Expressions pane. Then execute your code and see what the value of `ret` is in the Watch Expressions pane.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are saying "getColumnCell" and "mapCell" are both equal to functions, try outputting both variables, instead of the raw functions themselves.